# Image Behind Centered Page?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML/CSS that I came up with, I have centered the page and attempted to get an image either side (or behind it) of the centered page but I'm not sure how.

Sorry for the bad explanation, here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

      body {
        background-image: url("/images/background.png")
        }

      #wrap {
        width: 700px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }

      hr.one {
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <title>ItzJavaCraft | Home</title>

    <div id="wrap">

      <h1 align="center">ItzJavaCraft</h1>
      <hr class="one">
      <p>More coming soon...</p>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to get the background.png to the left, and the right of the page.

P.S: Sorry of I have done anything incorrect here, I am new.

Any help would be great!

Thanks,

—ItzJavaCraft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to get one image the fullwidth and height of the screen in the background.

```css
body {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/400x300/ff66cc/ffffff&text=icon1") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}

#wrap {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

hr.one {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<title>ItzJavaCraft | Home</title>

<div id="wrap">

  <h1 align="center">ItzJavaCraft</h1>
  <hr class="one">
  <p>More coming soon...</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's one simple error causing the background to not display: the relative URL should not start with "/" (unless, of course, you want to use an absolute path and are using a system where / refers to your root directory). Additionally, you'll need to use the background-size or background-repeat property to make the image fill up the entire page.

If you want your "wrap" element to remain white, you can just add a background-color to that element (adjusting the size of the element as necessary to get the coverage you're looking for).

Answer (score 0):

The background-image property sets one or more background images for an element. The background of an element is the total size of the element, including padding and border (but not the margin). By default, a background-image is placed at the top-left corner of an element, and repeated both vertically and horizontally.

> Tip: Always set a background-color to be used if the image is
>   unavailable..If you want to provide a position in a background image,
>   you can use some properties like:

Property:

```
background-position
```

Also, you can use a shorthand for that like jack blank code, but if this is hard to use for you, you can make it for separate like:

Full background image to your page:

```
background-position: cover;
```

Or if you want to change the position, you can use `center`, `left`, `right`, and `top`

For example:

```
background-position: center top;
```

or

```
background-position: left center;
```

or

```
background-position: top center;
```

etc.
You can learn about this property with more examples here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp